# How can I place an image to the far left in html?

Tags: css, html, web

I tried using the left align but it's still in the centre. I want the image in the far left. I have tried doing this in CSS but I can't find the right way to do it. I'm new to all this.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your css:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

that will all images put it in left side. If you want some specific image add class to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Your .class img

```css
.class img {
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}
```